# What is the flow of execution in the following functions?

Tags: scala, function

I dont undertand after of call `y(k)`, in the function "y"  what execute first? the parameters or the body 
the function. How the number 5 arrive at the function *k*

```
def k(x:Int) = x*x

def y(h:Int => Int) = h(5)

y(k)
```

OUTPUT:

```
25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the beauty of **Functional Programming** is that we can reason about or programs as expressions.

Given:

```
def k(x: Int) = x * x // 1.
def y(h: Int => Int) = h(5) // 2.
```

Then:

```
y(k) = k(5)  // By definition of y (2).
y(k) = 5 * 5 // By definition of k (1).
y(k) = 25    // By definition of multiplication.
```

---

*Here I made some simplifications. like I didn't do type checking, but that should be pretty straight forward.*